# error on hosting sencha touch app in googledrive

Tags: sencha-touch-2, web-hosting

when am trying to host my app in googledrive getting an error
just splash screen and continue on blinking with loader

try this link
https://51da17b21e519f2a1eb8d97ae6f8...1nVm8wZWJXNlk/

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
bootstrap.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClassPathMappings' of undefined
app.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.application is not a function

Comment: This url is not looking fine. https://someString...SomeString? Ensure this is the url for your hosted app.

Comment: Thanks droidpl please don't mistake this as any wrong link just am hosted with googledrive

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too, after using sencha CMD - upgrade command.
I was missing the 'touch' folder in my aplication root. 
copy-ing the touch folder from another project in my current project solved this.